# I can't seem to grep to work on a plain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner so pardon me for this rather simple question:

When I try to run the following code:

```
c = "hey there you you"
newarray = c.grep("you")
puts newarray
```

I get the error in ST2: `<main>': undefined method`grep' for "hey there you you":String (NoMethodError)

However, when I run this code using an array, it works:

```
c = ["hey", "there", "you"]
newarray = c.grep("you")
puts newarray
```

The example in the book I am learning from is showing example of grep being applied directly to a string, so I am not sure why this is happening. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5):

grep is an enumerable method so it can be applied to arrays and hashes.  "hey there you you" is a string so you are looking for `include?` or `match` or `scan`

```
"hey there you you".match 'you'
"hey there you you".scan 'you' # returns 2 results
```

Comment: AH I think the book is using an earlier version of ruby, which is why I was getting confused